# Horizontal glitches/lines/Screen tearing in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, 14.10, intel-graphics, screen

Why do I get horizontal lines like the ones shown below in my Ubuntu 14.10 acer aspire 4736z laptop as shown in [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUpWs.png) (see the icons of terminal, vuze, hardisk etc)? This happens some time (~10 min to 1hr) after starting the laptop. Not related to any particular application use I guess (This happens even when I am not running any application).

My laptop specs:
Acer aspire 4736z,
Ubuntu 14.10, 64bit OS, Unity,
3 GB ram,
750 GB hdd,
swap 3 gb,
dual boot with win7,
intel dual core processor:Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4400 @ 2.20GHz × 2,
Graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

The problem gets solved temporarily when I run the command

```
setsid unity
```

from terminal, but the problem resurfaces after some time (~10 min). The problem appears usually in launchers, menubars, top panel etc.

I am expecting the answer to have cause of the problem and solution for permanent fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trusty: Flickering problem with xorg opensource driver on ATI RV710 \[Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550\] \[1002:9552\]](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611422/trusty-flickering-problem-with-xorg-opensource-driver-on-ati-rv710-mobility-ra)