# Trusty: Flickering problem with xorg opensource driver on ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550] [1002:9552]

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg, radeon

Last week I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and since then I'm experiencing strange short horizontal flicker. It's hard to describe so [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/llz0dr0uhtyhzk6/2015-04-20%2000.55.28.mp4?dl=0) is a video of it and this is my current setup:

**lspci -nn | grep VGA**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550] [1002:9552]
```

**glxinfo | grep "renderer string"**

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV710
```

**Xorg -version**

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux zander-pc 3.16.0-34-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 17:49:16 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic root=UUID=dab06a14-8d7a-4d9d-a4da-24dee36894a9 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

My first thought was to install the proprietary ati driver (flgrx, legacy) but that messed up my xserver so badly that I had to reinstall Ubuntu again. So then I wondered why the problem had not occured with my old installation of Ubuntu 14.04. The only difference is that I'm now running a 64bit version.

So I think I'm stuck with the open source drivers, i.e. xserver-xorg-video-radeon, but that wouldn't be such a bad thing if this flickering problem could somehow be fixed. I did a lot of research and tried a bunch of things such as defining other options of the driver in /etc/X11/xorg.conf or specifying options for the module in /root/defaults/grub an running `grub-update` but none of this changed anything. I can't think of anything more to do.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or video recording of the problem?

Comment: Which proprietary driver broke your computer? `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 It was fglrx provided by the ati website. Later I read somewhere that the Mobility Radeon HD 4xxx series is not longer supported by fglrx under 14.04. If you could provide a save method of installing the correct proprietary driver without ending up reinstalling ubuntu again that would be awesome.

Comment: @Terrance8D I will try to provide a picture but i think it will be difficult to see

Comment: @Philipp Okay. I was wondering what the flickering looked like because I had a similar problem with my NVIDIA card.

Comment: @Terrance8D i added a video to my question. Is this what your Problem looked like?

Comment: @Philipp My flickering issue looked different, but I left an answer. It might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my laptops has the same problem.

The workaround for me is NOT to use any kernel above version 3.13.x-xx
(see the launchpad bug about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1479136 )

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks! Should have been my second idea though. I just ignored it for months now :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for flickering like this. First, install Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM) by typing into your terminal `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`, or search for it in the software center. When it's finished, open it up and scroll down to the Utility section. Make sure "Workarounds" is enabled. Click on it, and scroll down to the bottom. Enable "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint". If that doesn't solve the issue, also enable "Force complete redraw on initial damage".

Comment: thanks, but that didn't solve my problem. And "Force complete redraw ..." was already enabled.